# get items from 2 lists based on specific items values

Tags: c#

I have 2 lists of myType and let's myType has properties 
x y and z;

```
class myType 
{
  public int x {get;set;}
  public int y {get;set;}
  public int? z {get;set;}
} 

List<myType> list1 = new List<myType>();
List<myType> list2 = new List<myType>();
```

what I want to do is to get list with matched items between the 2 lists 
where `list1[i].x == list2[i].x && list1[i].y == list2[i].y` 
regardless the value of z

here's my code

```
     List<MiHHUserComponent> components ;
     List<MiHHUserComponent> dbComponents;
```

i need the items matched between 2 lists where 
`components[i].HHComponentFormName == dbComponents[i].HHComponentFormName
&& components[i].HHComponentName== dbComponents[i].HHComponentName`

i tried the code below

```
 for (int j = 0; j < hhUsersIDs.Count; j++)
     {
        var hhUser = hhUsersIDs[j]; 

        var results = (from l1 in dbComponents
                       join l2 in components
                       on new { l1.HHUserID, l1.HHComponentFormName,l1.HHComponentName } 
                       equals new {hhUser.HHUserID  ,l2.HHComponentFormName,l2.HHComponentName }
                       select new
                       {
                          // select whatever you want here, eg:
                          HHUserID = hhUser.HHUserID,
                          HHComponentFormName = l1.HHComponentFormName,
                          HHComponentName = l1.HHComponentName
                       }).ToList(); 
     }
```

i have 2 lists with different counts of elements
and they have matched items
I need new list contains the matched items  between them based on specific items in the the both lists
there's gonna be duplicate elements in the new list because the value 
of z will be taken from different value  in another list 
i hope that's clear now

Comment: Please insert your code- and then we will help you

Comment: If two items match on `x` and `y`, but `z` differs, how do you choose which value of `z` to use in the result?

Comment: i want to keep it null then edit it later

Comment: Hmm, but in your example `z` is an `int` and therefore cannot be null...

Comment: @MahmoudZakal Have you tried my answer below ?

Comment: @user3185569 
am checking it now

Comment: @MatthewWatson   
it's just an example not my real code 
i can define z as nullable

Comment: I guess just not setting it in the result will leave it as its default (null for reference types), which will be the correct value for your requirement.

Comment: @MahmoudZakal Any problem with my approach ?

Comment: You need to add some sample inputs and the expected output, because it's unclear what your requirement is.

Comment: ok just  a seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join using linq:

Make sure to add: `using System.Linq;`

```
var results = (from l1 in list1
                join l2 in list2
                on new { l1.x, l1.y } equals new { l2.x, l2.y }
                select new myType()
                {
                    // select whatever you want here, eg:
                    X = l1.x,
                    Y = l1.y,
                    Z = default(int) // or whatever the type of z is
                }).ToList();
```

Edit:

```
var results = (from l1 in dbComponents
                join l2 in components
                on new { l1.HHComponentFormName, l1.HHComponentName }
                equals new { l2.HHComponentFormName, l2.HHComponentName }
                where l1.HHUserID == hhUser.HHUserID
                select new myType()
                {
                    // select whatever you want here, eg:
                    HHUserID = hhUser.HHUserID,
                    HHComponentFormName = l1.HHComponentFormName,
                    HHComponentName = l1.HHComponentName
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: in my code one item in the second list i get it's value from different place 
so when i add it to join clause 
it gives me an error 
`one type on the expressions in the join clause is incorrect `

Comment: @MahmoudZakal Can you edit your question and post your join query ? I think you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MahmoudZakal you need to replace `hhUser.HHUserID` with `l2.HHUserID` in the join clause.

Comment: @MahmoudZakal if you really need `hhUser.HHUserID` in your query tell me, i can edit my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: yes i need it this 
l2.HHUserID will be null here so i want to fill it from hhUsers list while i do loop in hhUsers list 
so i add it each loop with new value of hhUsers.hhUserId

Comment: doesn't results here supposed to be of mytype ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with simple `linq` extension methods.

```
var rresult = list1.Where(x=>  list2.Any(l=>l.x ==x.x && l.y ==x.y));
```

Comment: Your code will give as result only matched item from the first list. He asked for matched items between the two lists.

Comment: Your alternative code will result with an empty set.

Comment: That means it returns _only_ common entries in the list. entry should present in both.

Comment: I'm updating that piece of code, can you remove your down vote please?

Answer (score 0):

```
var lookup1 = list1.ToLookup(t => new { t.x, t.y });
var lookup2 = list2.ToLookup(t => new { t.x, t.y });
var keys = lookup1.Where(t => lookup2.Contains(t.Key)).Select(t => t.Key);
return keys.SelectMany(t => lookup1[t].Concat(lookup2[t]));
```