# Get matched and unmatched elements from 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a Class named `Privileges`with the following properties `int UserId,string FormName,string CompName,int Privilege`

And I have 2 lists of `Privileges` type with different values as the sample below

```
List<Privileges> list1 = new List<Privileges>(){
            new Privileges(){UserId= 1,FormName="Form1",CompName="Button1",Privilege=2},
            new Privileges(){UserId= 2,FormName="Form1",CompName="Button3",Privilege=3},
            new Privileges(){UserId= 3,FormName="Form2",CompName="Button2",Privilege=2}
        };

        List<Privileges> list2 = new List<Privileges>(){
            new Privileges(){UserId= 5,FormName="Form1",CompName="Button1",Privilege=2},
            new Privileges(){UserId= 2,FormName="Form1",CompName="Button3",Privilege=4},
            new Privileges(){UserId= 4,FormName="Form2",CompName="Button2",Privilege=3}
        };
```

I want to make 3 functions
I made the first one which returns matched elements between the 2 lists 
and the result is the following

```
{UserId= 2,FormName="Form1",CompName="Button3",Privilege=3}
```

The 2nd function should return elements that exist in the first list and not in the second list, with the following result

```
{UserId= 1,FormName="Form1",CompName="Button1",Privilege=2},
{UserId= 3,FormName="Form2",CompName="Button2",Privilege=2}
```

The 3rd function should return elements that exist in the second list and not in the first list, with the following result

```
{UserId= 5,FormName="Form1",CompName="Button1",Privilege=2},
{UserId= 4,FormName="Form2",CompName="Button2",Privilege=3}
```

The matching clause should compare `UserId,FormName,CompName` values regardless what the value of `privilege` is.

[you can check my code snippet here](http://rextester.com/UHKRS17024)

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code to your question.

Comment: you can check it in the code snippet

Comment: sounds a lot like [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38093592/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix yes but with different requirement

Comment: You need a left outer join.  See webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to write any complex LINQ statements for these (and many more) tasks. Just define an [`IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) and everything becomes almost ridiculously simple:

```
class PrivilegesComparer : IEqualityComparer<Privileges>
{
    public bool Equals(Privileges x, Privileges y)
    {
        return x.UserId == y.UserId
               && x.FormName == y.FormName
               && x.CompName == y.CompName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Privileges obj)
    {
        return (obj.UserId + obj.FormName + obj.CompName).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var comparer = new PrivilegesComparer();
var intersect = list1.Intersect(list2, comparer);
var l1Exceptl2 = list1.Except(list2, comparer);
var l2Exceptl1 = list2.Except(list1, comparer);
```

Which represent your first, second and third function, respectively.

That's quite different from writing a complex LINQ statement for each individual task.

Comment: like this generic solution, more than mine

Comment: i like this solution but could u tell me how can I give specific value of Privilege in case of intersect

Comment: Simply use  a Where on the  lists.

Answer (score 2):

Elements in `list1` not in `list2`

```
var itemsInList1NotInList2 = list1.Where(l1 => !list2.Any(l2 => l1.UserId == l2.UserId && l1.FormName == l2.FormName && l1.CompName == l2.CompName)).ToList();
```

Elements in `list2` not in `list1`

```
var itemsInList2NotInList1 = list2.Where(l2 => !list1.Any(l1 => l1.UserId == l2.UserId && l1.FormName == l2.FormName && l1.CompName == l2.CompName)).ToList();
```

Comment: I'd like to point that this solution is quite inefficient. More efficient solution should probably use [HashSet.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908036(v=vs.90).aspx) and that `HashSet` should use a [custom comparer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023424/how-to-use-comparer-for-a-hashset) that will ignore the value of `privilege`.

Comment: i will see it 
but in the current time i will use this solution 
thanks anyway